# AmChart reference attribute 'chart' not null when printing reference object but when trying to access state.chart the 'chart' attribute becomes null?

Tags: reactjs, amcharts

I'm referencing the AmChart like so:

```
ref={(e) => {if (e) {this.ch = e}}}
```

When I print `this.ch` in `componentDidMount`, I can see that the attribute `state` is present and the `chart` attribute is NOT null. However, when I try to access `this.ch.state.chart` it is null. When I print `this.ch.state` immediately after the previous console log which prints `this.ch`, the `chart` attribute is then null. Why is this attribute only null when I try to access it, but not when I print `this.ch`?

edit:

[image: Screenshot of logs]

Comment: Where are you doing the console.logs? Post that code so we can see the problem. I have no idea what could be happening based on what you posted.

Comment: What are you reffing? `state` won't exist on a ref. A ref is a DOM element.

Comment: Console logs are in componentDidMount. console.log(this.ch) will show state.chart as NOT null, while console.log(this.ch.state) will show chart as null.  See question with updated screenshot.

Comment: Your first console.log is the entire component, not your ref. No idea what the second one is. Why not use `this.state`? What are you trying to do with refs? Can you post your render method? Where are you adding the ref?

Comment: Okay, the first: console.log(this.ch), the second: console.log(this.ch.state). That's it. One says the state->chart is null, the other says it is not. They are the same this.ch. The ref is again added in the AmChart tag in render under `ref={(e) => {if (e) {this.ch = e}}}`. I am trying to call zoomToIndexes on the chart but I cannot do that with a null `chart` attribute.

Comment: Come on man, post your full component or I'm not able to help. Your refs shouldn't ever have state. Trying to read state from a ref doesn't make sense, that's why I'm so confused. Please post your full code or make a jsFiddle where you recreated the issue.

Comment: Here is the ref docs where they explain how and when they should be used: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html. You use them to get access to DOM elements, not state data.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40130490/resetting-zoom-on-amchart3-react-at-data-update -- people seem to be accessing the state for AmCharts there?

Comment: I looked through their docs and github and I didn't see anything about accessing state from a ref. I'm not sure that works.

Comment: Upon more testing, I found that on comonentDidUpdate that the `chart` attribute is not null and I can access `chart`. However this is a problem as componentDidUpdate is not called when leaving the page and coming back - I then do not have access to `chart` in that scenario. @Arman I did not do that anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether or not the above method is the proper way to access `chart`, you can instead use event listeners on AmCharts to access the chart and make changes. Under 'options' in the AmChart element tag, add a listener:

```
   "listeners": [{
            "event": "rendered",
            "method": (e)=>{e.chart.doSomething()};
            }
    }]
```